# NodeJS Google Maps API Waiting

Tags: node.js, google-maps

```
for(i =0; i < data.length; i++){
                console.log("i is " + i);
                 var test= data[i].payload.id;
                console.log(test);
              if(recentarray.indexOf(test)==-1){
                recentarray.push(test);
              each_device_recent_long.push(data[i].payload.long);
              each_device_recent_lat.push(data[i].payload.lat);
              each_device_recent_id.push(data[i].payload.id);
              var address;
              googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({
                //address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
                latlng: [ each_device_recent_lat[i], each_device_recent_long[i]]
              }, function(err, response) {
                if (!err) {
                  console.log("here are the results from google");
                  console.log(response.json.results[0].formatted_address);
                  address = response.json.results[0].formatted_address;
                  //res.render('sigfox-logs', { print_recent_array: print_recent_array});
                }
              });
                print_recent_array.push([data[i].payload.id,data[i].payload.long,data[i].payload.lat,address]);
              }
            }
            res.render('sigfox-logs', {title:'Item Locations',
                                      entries:data,
                                      sensorLong:recent_long,
                                      sensorLat: recent_lat,
                                      each_device_recent_long:  each_device_recent_long,
                                      each_device_recent_lat:   each_device_recent_lat,
                                      each_device_recent_id :each_device_recent_id,
                                    print_recent_array: print_recent_array  });
```

I am trying to make an API call to google maps reverse geoencoding service. This is all working fine,  but it is taking a while to get the info back from google and the information rendered out to the HTML is "undefined" despite the fact that the placenames are showing in the console log, after the page has been rendered.

I know it has to do with callbacks and I have investigated the "request" library but it seems that the googleMapsClient object will be easier to deal with as the site grows.

Can someone help me find a way to make the res.render wait until the info has come back from the google API?
Thanks.

Comment: If you format your code you might get better responses.  But your response needs to be in the callback from the API call. Why do you have that response commented out?

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks like your code isn't account for the asynchronous nonblocking nature of Node Js.

The approach needs to be

1. Figure out all the requests you need ot make
2. Make said requests
3. wait for them all to return
4. if the results don't include the request information you will need to reconcile against the request (this may be difficult)
5. format your response to the http response

using a promise for this: googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode will help immensely. Convert it to a promise (reverseGeocodePromise)

```
var localeTupleArray = zip(each_device_recent_lat, each_device_recent_long)
var promises = map(
    reverseGeocodePromise, 
    localeTupleArray
)

all(promises).then(function(responses) {

})
```

where converting to a

- converting to a promise
- map
- zip
- all

are left as an exercise for the programmer

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are errors in here, but this is the basic concept:

```js
var data = []
var recentarray = []
var each_device_recent_long = [];
var each_device_recent_lat = [];
var each_device_recent_id = [];
var print_recent_array = [];

//map loops through array, passes all values through callback function, and returns a new array
var promises = data.map(function(item) {
  //creates a promise that takes a callback. you decide with to resolve/reject promise 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var test = item.payload.id
    if (recentarray.indexOf(test) == -1) {
      recentarray.push(test);
      each_device_recent_long.push(item.payload.long);
      each_device_recent_lat.push(item.payload.lat);
      each_device_recent_id.push(item.payload.id);
      var address;
      googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({
        //address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
        latlng: [each_device_recent_lat[i], each_device_recent_long[i]]
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("here are the results from google");
          console.log(response.json.results[0].formatted_address);
          address = response.json.results[0].formatted_address;
          //res.render('sigfox-logs', { print_recent_array: print_recent_array});
          print_recent_array.push([item.payload.id, item.payload.long, item.payload.lat, address])
          resolve(address)

        } else {
          reject(err)
        }
      });

    }
  })
})

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function(result) {
    res.render('sigfox-logs', {
      title: 'Item Locations',
      entries: result,
      sensorLong: recent_long,
      sensorLat: recent_lat,
      each_device_recent_long: each_device_recent_long,
      each_device_recent_lat: each_device_recent_lat,
      each_device_recent_id: each_device_recent_id,
      print_recent_array: print_recent_array
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.send({
      error: err
    })
  })
```